# Is 0x0000ffff the default load count of a dll in windows?

Tags: windows, dll, windbg

Using windbg, got the list of dlls with load count by `!dlls` command. Observed that the load count is `0x0000ffff` for many loaded dlls.
Is that a default value ?
Is that mean anything else ?

```
      0x00262fa8: C:\WINDOWS\system32\ole32.dll
      Base   0x774e0000  EntryPoint  0x774fd0b9  Size        0x0013d000
      Flags  0x80084006` LoadCount   0x0000ffff  TlsIndex    0x00000000
             LDRP_STATIC_LINK
             LDRP_IMAGE_DLL
             LDR**strong text**P_ENTRY_PROCESSED
             LDRP_PROCESS_ATTACH_CALLED
```

Comment: LDRP_STATIC_LINK is the hint.  Setting the load count to a high value avoids disaster when the program calls LoadLibrary("ole32.dll") and calls FreeLibrary() twice :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [The Covert Way to find the Reference Count of DLL](http://www.securityxploded.com/dllrefcount.php):

The load count for a DLL is a 16-bit value. If that value, treated as a signed short, is -1 (0xfffff) it indicates the DLL is statically linked, otherwise it's dynamically loaded.

Comment: If the DLL is statically linked, will the load count have any affect during `FreeLibrary` ?

Comment: I don't know if the OS treats that value specially (and doesn't decrement it) or if it goes ahead and decrements it.  It should be easy for you to write a test for that scenario. I have my guess (since it's valid to `LoadLibrary()`/`FreeLibrary()` a DLL that has been statically linked), but you should run some tests yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Additional information to the selected answer:

If the DLL is not linked statically (no LDRP_STATIC_LINK flag present), it also can mean that the DLL may be loaded with the GET_MODULE_HANDLE_EX_FLAG_PIN flag using [GetModuleHandleExA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-getmodulehandleexa) causing the reference count to be 0xffff. This prevents unloading the DLL no matter how many times FreeLibrary is called.