# Meaning of windbg !dlls output

Tags: dll, windbg

Does anyone know where I can find documentation about the output of windbg command !ddls? I'm mostly interested in the meaning of the Flags and LoadCount parameters, and what does it mean when the value of LoadCount is 0xffffffff.

I spent a day searching for this information on the NET, but didn't find anything useful.

Thanks in advance,

Andre

Comment: Avoid asking for the Missing Manual, unlikely you'll find somebody willing to write it and maintain it for the next 20 years.  A LoadCount of -1 is a simple way to prevent an app from accidentally unloading an implicitly loaded DLL with FreeLibrary().

Comment: @HansPassant: I've asked Microsoft whether I could maintain a copy of the WinDbg help file, publish it as a website and integrate community feedback. I didn't get a response. Maybe I should do it anyway...

Comment: As a side note, `Flags` and `LoadCount` are retrieved from `_LDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY` structure (see `_PEB.Ldr` member and `_PEB_LDR_DATA` structure [xxxOrderModuleList members])

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This link should help  - [Is 0x0000ffff the default load count of a dll in windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22855932/is-0x0000ffff-the-default-load-count-of-a-dll-in-windows)

Snip from the same `The load count for a DLL is a 16-bit value. If that value, treated as a signed short, is -1 (0xfffff) it indicates the DLL is statically linked, otherwise it's dynamically loaded.`